# Elasticsearch ERROR, The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

AWS Elasticsearch cluster connects through nodejs.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch')
const awsHttpClient = require('http-aws-es')

let client = elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'http://---.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/',
    connectionClass: awsHttpClient,
    amazonES: {
        region: 'us-east-1',
        credentials: new AWS.Credentials('----', '-----')
    }
});

client.search({
    index: 'orders',
    type: 'text',
    body: {
        query: {
            match: {
                source: 'ETH'
            }
        }
    }
})
.then(res => console.log("Error : ",res));
```

> Elasticsearch ERROR: 2021-08-28T07:40:03Z   Error: Request error,
> retrying   POST
> http://-------.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/eth_orders/_search?type=text
> => The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined
> at Log.error (C:\Users\genie\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\log.js:239:56)
> at checkRespForFailure (C:\Users\genie\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\transport.js:298:18)
> at done (C:\Users\genie\node_modules\http-aws-es\connector.js:48:7)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
>
> Elasticsearch WARNING: 2021-08-28T07:40:03Z   Unable to revive
> connection:
> http://-----.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/
>
> Elasticsearch WARNING: 2021-08-28T07:40:03Z   No living connections
>
> (node:18256) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No Living
> connections
> at sendReqWithConnection (C:\Users\genie\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\transport.js:266:15)
> at next (C:\Users\genie\node_modules\elasticsearch\src\lib\connection_pool.js:243:7)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created) (node:18256)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise
> rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 1) (node:18256) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
> that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
> non-zero exit code.

I am getting these errors can anyone help out.

Answer (score 0):

Doctypes are not available in latest Elasticsearch version so probably just remove `type: 'text',`

```
client.search({
    index: 'orders',
    body: {
        query: {
            match: {
                source: 'ETH'
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Its connection error, what I have to do for that.